# Email Headers: Anything to indicate file size?

Tags: email, smtp, header, pop3

I need to know the file size of email attachments before downloading them. Is there anything in email headers that can help me?

Comment: You asked this already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221322/determine-filesize-of-email-attachment-before-downloading

Comment: Other question was dealing with PHP, Zend mail library. This question relates specifically to email headers. PHP expert != email headers expert.

Comment: Unless you're looking to do the same thing in two entirely different and independent ways then you could easily have incorporated this into your other question as the information about the file size is the same, and seeing as your earlier question was still unanswered, materially the same and asked only a little before this one you could have rewritten/added to it without too much issue. The question is essentially "is there any way of telling the file size of an email attachment before download?" if you need to rewrite it for every single possibility this site will be full.

Comment: There is a limit to the number of tags one can assign to each question. By tagging them differently, I hope to reach different experts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in POP3, but you can do this with the BodyStructure in IMAP4.

Comment: In POP3 the only information you can get is the size of entire message (C : RETR 1 S: +OK 28 octets)